# Помогите с тире 3

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли поставить в данном случае тире?

*У меня две формы обучения — домашняя и очная — и я не знаю, какое расписание у меня будет.*

Answer (score 2):

Тире (второе) не может отменить запятую перед второй частью сложносочинённого предложения.

При другом порядке слов, например:

*У меня две — домашняя и очная — формы обучения, и я не знаю, какое расписание у меня будет*,

оба тире будут на месте, они обособляют уточнение.

Если сохранить заданный порядок слов, то единственно возможна такая пунктуация:

***У меня две формы обучения — домашняя и очная, и я не знаю, какое расписание у меня будет.***

Comment: Галина, а нормально, что Вы пример-предложение закончили запятой, и продолжили большое предложение, содержащее пример? Никогда просто с таким не сталкивался, вот и удивляюсь. Звучит то есть очень даже складно на слух, но запятая в конце предложения меня всё-таки смущает. Если так действительно оформляют, будет даже приятно об этом узнать.))

Comment: Тёмыч, курсивное выделение заменяет кавычки: *При другом порядке слов, например: "У меня две — домашняя и очная — формы обучения, и я не знаю, какое расписание у меня будет",
оба тире будут на месте, они обособляют уточнение.* Или: *При другом порядке слов (например, "У меня две — домашняя и очная — формы обучения, и я не знаю, какое расписание у меня будет"),
оба тире будут на месте, они обособляют уточнение.*

Comment: Да что курсив кавычки заменяет я понимаю, я сам так делаю предложения курсивом вместо кавычек, хотя словосочетания часто выделяю и тем, и тем (так больше нравится). Я не об этом. Меня смущает запятая после *будет,* которое хоть и не заканчивает Вашу фразу, но заканчивает фразу-пример. Так правильно оформлять? На самом деле, что-то мне подсказывает, что так можно, и так и хочется делать. Действительно, когда я ставил кавычки, то включал фразы-примеры в предложение и, если и не ставил запятую, то никакого знака. В общем, выходит, можно что угодно ставить, да?

Answer (score 2):

У меня две формы обучения — домашняя и очная, и я не знаю, какое расписание у меня будет.

Я согласна с вариантом Галины, но **объяснить** попробую следующим образом.

Обособленную конструкцию  "домашняя и очная" можно оформить (1) **по принципу вставки** (сохраняя два тире) или (2) по принципу **обособленного приложения** (встроенная конструкция, второе тире поглощается запятой). Лучше выбрать второй вариант, так как обособленное приложение имеет значение **уточнения**, то есть связано  по смыслу  с предложением, в то время как вставка —  это **грамматически самостоятельная конструкция**.